# How to use apply to get hpfilter for multiple column?

Tags: r

I am trying to get the hpfilter for multiple columns of data that I have with this code, but I got an error "Error in is.ts(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default". I would appreciate any suggestion on how to get the hpfilter for multiple column. Thank you.

```
 hp_filter1 <- apply(dataset[,2:ncol(dataset)],2, hpfilter(freq=1600, type="lambda"))
```

Comment: Try `hp_filter1 <- apply(dataset[, -1],2, hpfilter, freq=1600, type="lambda")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` as -

```
hp_filter1 <- apply(dataset[, -1],2, hpfilter, freq=1600, type="lambda")
```

Or to correct your approach use an anonymous function which will be clearer.

```
hp_filter1 <- apply(dataset[,2:ncol(dataset)],2, function(x) 
                    hpfilter(x, freq=1600, type="lambda"))
```

Since you are applying the function to each column you can also use `lapply`/`sapply`.